# update or delete on table "users_user" violates foreign key constraint "articles_article_users_user_id"id=5 still referenced from table "articles_arti

Tags: django, django-models, constraints

I am working with Django v4.* and I have linked 2 table/model `Users` and `Articles` and my aim is when user is deleted I don't want to delete the article or vice versa, so I referenced user `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING` in the Article model, but I am getting this error when I tried to delete a user, it seems to my that DO_NOTHING is not working the way I thought it does?How I can pass this and achieve what I tend to do without getting constrain error? Thanks

```
class Article(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=355)
     author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, 
     related_name='articles')
     .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference not existing PK in most of DBs. If you want to leave Article after deleting User you should do something like that:

```
class Article(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=355)
     author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, 
     related_name='articles')
 .....
```

This way, when you are deleting referenceed user, author will be set to null in DB.

Comment: You can read more about usage of DO_NOTHING here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING